# На мансарде или в мансарде

Tags: предлоги

Какой предлог лучше использовать: на/в мансарде?

Answer (score 1):

Смотря в каком аспекте употребляется:

> Подыскивая жильё, он остановил свой выбор **на** мансарде - с тех пор **в**
>   мансарде и живёт.

Мансарда - *жилое помещение*, в отличие от чердака, аналогичного по расположению в доме (**в** мансарде, но **на** чердаке). Предлог местонахождения (**в**) аналогично сочетается с "комнатой".

Comment: А допустимо "подниматься по лестнице **на** мансарду"? Слух, вроде, не режет, или это просто распространённая ошибка?

Comment: Видимо, так можно: в этом случае под мансардой понимается _этаж_, высотный уровень. У строителей именно "лестница **на** мансарду". Но затем через дверь входят **в** мансарду.